# Trying to install Bright Game Panel (PHP/Apache)

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error "MySQL extension could not be found or is not installed. Please recompile your Apache with the MySQL extension included." for my Bright Game Panel. [image]

You can see from the picture that everything except this is working. My sql server is running.

Answer (score 1):

Find another piece of software.

This software requires the old PHP `mysql` extension, which was deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed entirely in PHP 7.0.